# MVC Session to store data

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there other ways in MVC to store data instead of using a session variable?  I would like to have an data object available for a given session. I have only used session var in the past and wondering if there are new ways to hold data on the server side similar to a session state var.

Comment: Sure.  What are your requirements that session variables do not provide?

Comment: I am fine with Session Vars.. was just curious if there were other methods introduced in MVC or new .net stuff

Answer (score 0):

Most of the *new* stuff in MVC (TempData, etc) are actually stored in Session.

That being said, there isn't any new storage for session specific information in ASP.Net MVC.  This is due to the fact that any new technology isn't going to be MVC specific (just as Session isn't) it's just going to be ASP>Net specific.  Now considering Session supports In-Proc, SQL, and more, it has (as far as I've needed) all the features needed, I don't believe we'll ever see any new *session storage framework/technology* in ASP.Net (except maybe in vNet).

Comment: So if I want to store a Model and have it sitting around. I would store it in a session? That is what I am doing now. was just thinking if there were other ways.. Thanks for the answer

Comment: That is really vague question, thus I can't answer it reliably.  I don't know why you want to store it.  I don't know it's size.  I don't know how often you need access or if that model is used by only that single users, multiple users, or all users.